# Group by Hourly + Display

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, group-by

I have a database which looks like that:

```
ID  gesamtzaehler   gutzaehler  timestamp
1   7119529 7007905 2023-03-01 14:09:15.043
2   7119553 7007929 2023-03-01 14:10:15.013
3   7119577 7007953 2023-03-01 14:11:15.043
4   7119601 7007977 2023-03-01 14:12:15.030
5   7119625 7008001 2023-03-01 14:13:15.047
6   7119649 7008025 2023-03-01 14:14:15.010
7   7119673 7008049 2023-03-01 14:15:15.010
8   7119697 7008073 2023-03-01 14:16:15.027
9   7119721 7008097 2023-03-01 14:17:15.027
10  7119731 7008107 2023-03-01 14:18:15.043
11  7119731 7008107 2023-03-01 14:19:15.057
12  7119731 7008107 2023-03-01 14:20:15.040
13  7119731 7008107 2023-03-01 14:21:15.010
```

and want to get the hourly greatest difference between Gesamtzaehler and Gutzaehler.
Everything works fine like that:

```
SELECT        MAX(gesamtzaehler - gutzaehler) - MIN(gesamtzaehler - gutzaehler) AS Ausschuss, CAST(DATEPART(Hour, timestamp) AS varchar) + ':00' AS Hour
FROM            dbo.Zaehler
WHERE        (timestamp >= DATEADD(hour, - 24, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, timestamp)
```

The Answer of the Statement is this:

```
Ausschuss Hour
12  0:00
13  23:00
6   15:00
14  3:00
3   6:00
11  21:00
63  7:00
4   1:00
14  18:00
19  4:00
25  19:00
7   5:00
0   22:00
5   16:00
15  2:00
29  17:00
4   20:00
2   14:00
```

And here is my problem. For my visualization I need the Hour column to be sorted. As for example a timestamp can be sorted. If it is 7 ' O-Clock the sorting mechanism should bring the result (like order by timestamp 8-24-7)... it will in this example always sort from 0 - 24.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Order by char_length(Hour), Hour?

Comment: However, doesn't SQL Server have any hour to minute data type?

Comment: keep the `Hour` as integer `DATEPART(Hour, timestamp)` don't convert to string. Then you can sort it . Format it to the required format in your presentation layer

Comment: If i take the hour as integer and order it by hour -> it will order from 0 - 24

i want to use this information as a chart.
so if i open the chart at 7 O-Clock i want to be ordered from 8:00 the previous day to 7 today... that sorting only works with timestamp datatype in sql and that is my problem at the moment.

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN hr < DAREPART(HOUR, GETDATE())  THEN 24 + hr ELSE hr END`

Comment: Add another column, extract just Datepart( Hour, ...) and use this to sort. And depending on version of SQL use Concat( Format( Datepart( hh, Sysdatetime() ), '00' ), ':00' ) to format your hour display instead of double casting.

Answer (score 0):

If we take a slightly modified version of your example data (it's really helpful if you provide this as reproducible DDL/DML when asking questions):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID BIGINT, gesamtzaehler BIGINT, gutzaehler BIGINT, timestamp DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, gesamtzaehler, gutzaehler, timestamp) VALUES
(1 , 7119529, 7007534, '2023-03-01 17:09:15.043'),(2 , 7119553, 7007543, '2023-03-01 17:10:15.013'),(3 , 7119577, 7007954, '2023-03-01 17:11:15.043'),(4 , 7119881, 7007977, '2023-03-01 17:12:15.030'),
(5 , 7119625, 7008225, '2023-03-01 18:13:15.047'),(6 , 7119649, 7008555, '2023-03-01 18:14:15.010'),(7 , 7119673, 7008045, '2023-03-01 18:15:15.010'),(8 , 7119657, 7008073, '2023-03-01 18:16:15.027'),
(9 , 7119721, 7008254, '2023-03-01 18:17:15.027'),(10, 7119731, 7008444, '2023-03-01 19:18:15.043'),(11, 7119731, 7008107, '2023-03-01 19:19:15.057'),(12, 7119531, 7008107, '2023-03-01 19:20:15.040'),
(13, 7119731, 7008987, '2023-03-01 20:21:15.010'),(14, 7119529, 7007653, '2023-03-02 07:09:15.043'),(15, 7119553, 7007978, '2023-03-02 07:10:15.013'),(16, 7119567, 7007953, '2023-03-02 07:11:15.043'),
(17, 7119601, 7007321, '2023-03-02 07:12:15.030'),(18, 7119625, 7008444, '2023-03-02 08:13:15.047'),(19, 7119649, 7008099, '2023-03-02 08:14:15.010'),(70, 7119573, 7008049, '2023-03-02 09:15:15.010'),
(21, 7119697, 7008277, '2023-03-02 09:16:15.027'),(22, 7119721, 7008044, '2023-03-02 09:17:15.027'),(23, 7119731, 7008124, '2023-03-02 10:18:15.043'),(24, 7119761, 7008107, '2023-03-02 10:19:15.057'),
(25, 7119731, 7008107, '2023-03-02 12:20:15.040'),(26, 7119222, 7008333, '2023-03-02 12:21:15.010');
```

Then we can do something like this:

```
;WITH Hours AS (
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-DATEPART(MILLISECOND,GETDATE()),DATEADD(SECOND,-DATEPART(SECOND,GETDATE()),DATEADD(MINUTE,-DATEPART(MINUTE,GETDATE()),DATEADD(hour, - 24, GETDATE())))) AS DateTime
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,1,DateTime)
  FROM Hours
 WHERE DateTime < GETDATE()
)

SELECT h.DateTime, CAST(h.DateTime AS TIME) AS Time, a.Ausschuss
  FROM Hours h
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                     SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,DATEPART(HOUR,timestamp),CAST(CAST(timestamp AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) AS DateTime, 
                            MAX(gesamtzaehler - gutzaehler) - MIN(gesamtzaehler - gutzaehler) AS Ausschuss
                       FROM @Table
                      GROUP BY DATEADD(HOUR,DATEPART(HOUR,timestamp),CAST(CAST(timestamp AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                    ) a
      ON h.DateTime = a.DateTime
 ORDER BY h.DateTime
```

| DateTime | Time | Ausschuss |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-01 16:00:00.000 | 16:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-01 17:00:00.000 | 17:00:00.0000000 | 387 |
| 2023-03-01 18:00:00.000 | 18:00:00.0000000 | 534 |
| 2023-03-01 19:00:00.000 | 19:00:00.0000000 | 337 |
| 2023-03-01 20:00:00.000 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 0 |
| 2023-03-01 21:00:00.000 | 21:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-01 22:00:00.000 | 22:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-01 23:00:00.000 | 23:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 00:00:00.000 | 00:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 01:00:00.000 | 01:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 02:00:00.000 | 02:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 03:00:00.000 | 03:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 04:00:00.000 | 04:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 05:00:00.000 | 05:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 06:00:00.000 | 06:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 07:00:00.000 | 07:00:00.0000000 | 705 |
| 2023-03-02 08:00:00.000 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 369 |
| 2023-03-02 09:00:00.000 | 09:00:00.0000000 | 257 |
| 2023-03-02 10:00:00.000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 47 |
| 2023-03-02 11:00:00.000 | 11:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 12:00:00.000 | 12:00:00.0000000 | 735 |
| 2023-03-02 13:00:00.000 | 13:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 14:00:00.000 | 14:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 15:00:00.000 | 15:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 16:00:00.000 | 16:00:00.0000000 | NULL |
| 2023-03-02 17:00:00.000 | 17:00:00.0000000 | NULL |

What are we doing here? First, we build out a CTE to give us all the hours from our start time (24 hours ago) until now. This let's us have a row for each hour, even though it may not be present in the data.
Then we LEFT OUTER JOIN to our aggregated data to get the values for that hour.
In the sub query, we're aggregating the data up in a similar way to your example, but we're preserving the data type of DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL-Server 2022, you can directly order by [datetrunc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function.

If you are using an older version of SQL-Server, you can use the following code([dateadd()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [datediff()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) to truncate timestamps to hour and then order by truncated timestamps.

```
dateadd(HOUR, datediff(HOUR,0,timestamp),0)
```

Here is the quey:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(gesamtzaehler - gutzaehler) - MIN(gesamtzaehler - gutzaehler) AS Ausschuss, 
    CAST(DATEPART(Hour, dateadd(HOUR, datediff(HOUR,0,timestamp),0)) AS varchar) + ':00' AS Hour
FROM  Zaehler
WHERE (timestamp >= DATEADD(hour, - 24, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY dateadd(HOUR, datediff(HOUR,0,timestamp),0)
ORDER BY dateadd(HOUR, datediff(HOUR,0,timestamp),0)
```